# Is it possible to change the Windows fonts folder to default?

Tags: windows

I've installed a deleted a bunch of fonts, and have somehow broken something. Is there a way to restore my fonts to 'factory default'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the original installation media, you will find a file named `install.wim` in the `sources` folder:

[image]

You will be able to open that file using [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Inside that file, you will find a folder named `1`. In there, you'll see the familiar folder structure from your system drive:

[image]

Go to `Windows\Fonts` and simply extract all the files and copy them to your `%WINDIR%\Fonts` folder.

[image]

Comment: Wow, never would have expected it to be that easy.